# Python: converting list to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pygame

I have a list stored in a variable and I am trying to convert this list into a dictionary with with dictionary keys corresponding to their respective list index.  The point is to create a list of images and rects to blit (which isn't shown here but I've tested that that portion of the code does indeed work). 
 Here's the code:

```
hand = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png']
tempHand = hand
finTempHand = {}
newTempHand = ["pygame.image.load("+tempHand+")" for t in tempHand]
print(newTempHand)
for i in range(0,len(newTempHand)):
    finTempHand[i] = newTempHand[i]
```

and I am getting this error:

```
newTempHand = ["pygame.image.load("+tempHand+")" for t in tempHand]
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: _"I have a list stored in a variable and I am trying to convert this list into a dictionary with with dictionary keys corresponding to their respective list index."_ - `tempHand = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(hand)}`?

Comment: Wrong variable. You should be using `t` instead of `tempHand`.

Comment: Something like this
`newTempHand = ["pygame.image.load("+t+")" for t in tempHand]`

Comment: @ChristianDean Jeez I used enumate in my code later, why didn't I think of this??

Comment: @Aran-Fey You are correct

Comment: @Rehan Azher this worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented and helped, you have helped me quite a bit and I greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that using dictionary comprehension.

```
hand = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png']
finTempHand = {
    i: "pygame.image.load({})".format(x) 
        for i, x in enumerate(hand)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using the wrong variable

```
newTempHand = ["pygame.image.load("+tempHand+")" for t in tempHand]
```

should be

```
newTempHand = ["pygame.image.load("+t+")" for t in tempHand]
```

Second you can use a dict comprehension and also remove that 0 from the range

Full code:

```
    hand = ['Lakers_01.png', 'Lakers_02.png', 'Lakers_03.png', 'Lakers_04.png']

    finTempHand = {
        i: 'pygame.image.load({})'.format(current)
        for index, current in enumerate(hand)
    }
```

Final result inspired in @Rhaul 's answer bellow